# why and when the custom directive will be declared as the comment type in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I recently have been asked this question in an interview.
why and when (under what scenario) the custom directive will be declared as the comment type in angular.js?

Can some one explain this in detail?

Answer (score 2):

You should not use this feature, because it's bad practice.
For example if you use a minifier for your production code and you set the flag "remove comments" to true, your app suddenly will stop working.
This is bad !

The feature itself was added for compatibility reasons.
A lot of other frameworks offered options to use comments for meta information. This is why google decided to support it as well.
Nevertheless they recommend not to use it at all.

Furthermore it was used in edge cases where you needed your directive to span multiple elements. But this is obsolete since Angular 1.2 introducing ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end.

See officialy doc for this:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

> **Best Practice**: Comment directives were commonly used in places where
>   the DOM API limits the ability to create directives that spanned
>   multiple elements (e.g. inside `<table>` elements). AngularJS 1.2
>   introduces **ng-repeat-start** and **ng-repeat-end** as a better solution to
>   this problem. Developers are encouraged to use this over custom
>   comment directives when possible.

So to your question "when to use comment type directive": never ;)